# How to code add method in double linked list using interface?

Tags: java, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I have to code the add method in List using interface. i tried but its not even working. can anyone help me. interface and list class are given below:

```
/**
 * Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. 
 *  Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent 
 *  elements to the right (adds one to their indices).
 * @param index Index at which to add
 * @param obj The object to add
 * @return True if insertion was successful
 */
public boolean add(int index, Token obj) {
    // implement this
}
```

Comment: And what is not working?

Comment: i want to know how to implement that function @Lino

Comment: Do you have problems because you don't know *how to implement any method in java* or because you don't know *how to implement this specific add method*?

Comment: I dont know how to implement this specific method @Lino

Comment: Take a look at the implementation of this `add` method in the `LinkedList` class, this should give you an idea

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow - we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems - but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: i tried with these code but its not working

Comment: @jhalockbhandari please explain what is not working and read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @lino  if head is null it  throw exception then  i add  two new node called head tail (null,null,obj)and set head as current node and return true at last Now its not working till this. what i am supposed to do. my other code such as isempty get contains size are working '

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert an item at a given position in a linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076364/how-to-insert-an-item-at-a-given-position-in-a-linked-list)

Comment: @jhalock bhandari Actually you haven't yet provided CODE, just the interface to implement. Add your code (node implementation, fields for head/tail of list, ...) and we're able to help you.

Comment: If you check out my profile, I have an answer written. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55268253/how-to-write-an-add-insert-method-with-a-doublylinkedlist-in-java

Comment: Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a somewhat double-linked list, which contains nodes like `(previous-node, next-node, stored-object)`:

Pseudocode (only valid for `index>0` and `index<list.size`)

- get node `N0` at `index-1` position
- get node `N1` at `index` position.
- create new node `Nn` with `(N0, N1, obj)`
- update `N0` `next-node` to `Nn`
- update `N1` `previous-node` to `Nn`
- return true.